# Mvvmcross Testing different view models fails when running together

Tags: xamarin, integration-testing, mvvmcross

I've come across an interesting error. I have two test files for my xamarin mobile application, both testing view models:

```
public class TestFirstViewModel : MvxIoCSupportingTest 
{

    public void AdditionalSetup() {
    //Register services and dependencies here.
    }

    [Fact]
    public TestMethod1() {
    // Successful test code here.
    }
}
```

That's in one file. In another file, I have:

```
public class TestSecondViewModel : MvxIoCSupportingTest 
{

    public void AdditionalSetup() {
    //Register services and dependencies here, slightly different from first
    }

    [Fact]
    public TestMethod2() {
    // Successful test code here.
    }
}
```

When I run these files individually (I'm using xunit), they work just fine. However, when I run them together, I get the following error on one of the test cases:

```
Result Message: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException : You cannot create more than one instance of MvxSingleton
Result StackTrace:  
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxSingleton`1..ctor()
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer..ctor(IMvxIocOptions options)
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize(IMvxIocOptions options)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core.MvxIoCSupportingTest.ClearAll()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core.MvxIoCSupportingTest.Setup()
   at Project.Test.TestFirstViewModel.TestMethod1() in ...
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Be sure to clear all MVX related instances on tear down.

Comment: Would that be with base.ClearAll() at tear down? I'm not entirely sure on the command

Comment: could you add the content of your setups ? some singleton is instanciated twice, see https://github.com/slodge/MonoCrossExtensions/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Core/MvxSingleton.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this question by changing testing frameworks. I had different ioc singleton initializations, because, well, they're different test cases and needed different inputs/mocks. Instead of using Xunit, I resorted to Nunit where their cache clearing was much more defined: Xunit doesn't exactly believe in setup and tear-down, so it made a test environment like this more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The issue stems from the parallelization of XUnit without the option to do proper tear-down. You could diable parallelization in the AssemblyIndo.cs file in you test project by adding:

```
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade some success with setup things in a constructor and add this check:

```
    public PaymentRepositoryTests()
    {
        if (MvxSingletonCache.Instance == null)
        {
            Setup();
        }

        //other registerings.
    }`
```

Also I did implement the IDisposable Interface

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        ClearAll();
    }
```

But tbh not sure how much impact that had..

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by using the collection attribute.

```
[Collection("ViewModels")]
class ViewModelATest : BaseViewModelTest {
...
}

[Collection("ViewModels")]
class ViewModelBTest : BaseViewModelTest {
...
}
```

The base view model test class has the mock dispatcher and performs the singleton registrations in the additional setup method.

Each of my tests calls `ClearAll()` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It works ok with xunit
Copy MvxIocSupportingTest and Mvxtest in your xunit PCL project.
Modify MvxTest to remove the attributes and use a simple contructor:

```
public class MvxTest : MvxIoCSupportingTest
{
    protected MockMvxViewDispatcher MockDispatcher { get; private set; }

    public MvxTest()
    {
        Setup();
    }
    ...
```

And in each of you test, derive from IClassFixture

```
public class TestRadiosApi : IClassFixture<MvxTest>
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestToken()
    {
    ...
```

xunit will create the MvxTest class only once for all tests.